# Disabling applications through group-policy

Tags: group-policy

How do I disable office applications from loading on client machines through group policy?

Comment: Found an answer:  http://blog.thejoshmeister.com/2004/12/disabling-applications-with-active.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your client versions, you could either use [a path rule in Software Restriction Policies (Windows 2000 and newer)](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/bb457006.aspx) or [AppLocker (Windows 7)](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/dd723678%28WS.10%29.aspx) through group policies to disallow the execution of certain applications for your users.